# How to get not so many digits in PHP

Tags: php, string, numbers, echo

```
<?php echo (($priceInt[0]-$specialInt[0])/$priceInt[0])*100 ?>
```

For every price this gives me something like 11,111111111 or 3,3433333333 
How can i limit it so i will get only 11 or 3 ? Without anything after " , ".

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at http://php.net/manual/fr/function.number-format.php

Use it like this :

```
echo number_format((($priceInt[0]-$specialInt[0])/$priceInt[0])*100, 0, '', '');
```

If you just need the integer part just use :

```
echo intval((($priceInt[0]-$specialInt[0])/$priceInt[0])*100);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[sprintf()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)** like below:

```
echo sprintf("%d",'3,3433333333'); //output : 3
```

or

```
echo sprintf("%d",'11,111111111'); //output : 11
```

In your case:

```
echo sprintf("%d",((($priceInt[0]-$specialInt[0])/$priceInt[0])*100));
```

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` -- it should be `printf()` without `echo` every time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot guys i fixed it

```
echo sprintf("%d",((($priceInt-$specialInt)/$priceInt)*100));
```

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` -- it should be `printf()` without `echo` every time.